# Inequality of means for functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, means

According to Wikipedia one can define the [arithmetic mean of an integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ over a relatively compact domain $M$ as:

$$A(f) = \frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M f$$

where $\mu(M)$ is the measure of $M$. Moreover, if $f > 0$ one can also define its geometric mean as:

$$G(f) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M \log f\right)$$

The [inequality of the arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) is a well-known result in the discrete case. ¿Is it also true in this context? That is, *is it true that*:

$$A(f) \geq G(f)$$

*for every positive integrable function $f$?*

Comment: It follows from Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality you have that for a concave function $h$ (usually it is stated for convex functions with the other way round inequality)

$$h\left(\frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M f\right) \ge \frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M h(f)$$

As the $\log$ is concave you get that

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M f\right) \ge \frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M \log(f)$$

As $e^x$ is increasing in $x$ the inequality is preserved when exponentiating, yielding to

$$e^{\log \left(\frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M f\right)} = \frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M f \ge \exp\left({\frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M \log(f)}\right)$$

Comment: Nice, thanks! I only knew the inequality in the discrete form. It seems the result could be generalized to any measure space using an almost identical proof which is good to know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form

Answer (score 1):

> Yes it is true: Use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality)

And $x\mapsto \exp (x)$ is convex. Then you get,

$$G(f) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M \log f\right)\le \frac{1}{\mu(M)}\int_M \exp(\log f)  = A(f)$$

That is 
$$G(f) \le A(f)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I decided to accept the other answer because it was better formatted but I appreciate the quick response